# Shut down and restart computer from search

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard

In Windows 8.1, is it possible to shut down or restart the computer using only the keyboard?

When you click the Windows key on the keyboard, on the overlay you get a nice search box. Typing in "restart" or "turn off" gives you an option called "Turn off your PC". When you click that you get a sidebar called "Settings"... which does not make much sense to me, but okay.

Anyway, what I was thinking was, click Windows key on keyboard, type "restart" and hit enter. That does not seem to work, so is there maybe a program/plugin/something that can be installed, or maybe a setting that can be enabled, to make this happen?

Comment: take a look here for the commands, specifically the shutdown.exe which is still valid for win8.1 http://superuser.com/questions/674087/how-to-shut-down-a-windows-8-1-pro-computer-in-remote-session?rq=1

Comment: If all you want to do is speed up these operations, simply create shortcuts to shutdown.exe with the appropriate arguments and assign keyboard shortcuts to them. Ctrl+Alt+S/R = boom, PC shuts down or restarts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows key + x  should show you the option "shut down or sign out"

This the equivalent of rightclicking the start button.

Comment: `Win + X` and then `U, U` to shut down, and `U, R` to restart.

Answer (score 3):

Use Alt+F4 to get to a shutdown dialog.

Comment: +1 I always forget Alt + F4 does more than close programs.

Comment: As this also closes windows, it only works if there are no windows open/everything is minimized. Good answer, though.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen You can Alt+Tab (or Windows+D) to the Desktop then Alt+F4.

Answer (score 0):

You could do 
'win +r' >
type 'cmd' >
type 'shutdown /s'

All from the keyboard and probably could be done in 15-20s

Comment: I am not shy about using the command line, but this seems like a somewhat "hacky" way of doing it.